# how to display an image after successfully submitting form in the same form page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have created a page that contains a form, I want to show an image that's hidden in the same page after successfully submitting the form, I'm trying to do it using JavaScript inside the PHP code.

here is the code

html code:

```
        <label for="UserEmail">Email</label> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <input type="text" name="UserEmail" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>
        <label for="UserEmail">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="UserPass" placeholder="Enter Password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">&nbsp&nbsp
        <button>click</button>
        <a href="securityQ.html">Forgot password</a>&nbsp&nbsp
        <a href="register.html">New !! register </a>
        <div id="imge">
            <img src="profile.png" alt="Profile Image">
        </div>
    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$x ="hi";
$y ="1";
if(($_POST["UserEmail"]==$x) and ($_POST["UserPass"]==$y))
{ 
    echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('img').style.display='block';
        </script>";
        header("location: index.html");
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Login Faild');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use jQuery with ajax to submit the form, and when you submit the form successfully and insert the data in database and upload the image into the folder, then return that image's location and in the jQuery's success method, use that image location to display image on any specific element using jQuery selector and make that element visible

Comment: can you share some code of the solution pls, I'm not using a DB right now just variables with static values to represent the DB